# Hyphen – or 'to'

Tags: punctuation

I have a general quesiton. Do you usually use hypens – to write about a range? Or do you use 'to'. Here I have two examples

"Table 2 – Table 5 show ... " or "Table 2 to Table show ..."

"From 8:00 – 11:00 the engines were running" or "From 8:00 to 11:00 the engines were running"

I ask this because I was always using the hypen. Last month a text of mine was corrected by a professional language service (with native speakers) and the changed all my hyphens to 'to'.

What is your take on that? I'd appreciate every answer.

Comment: A hyphen is a very short dash. Yours looks like an en dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranges using hyphens are better used in tables where several of them are being compared or listed. It is common to use *to* if only since that will be what a speaker will read from the sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Elliot. Would you also use 'to' for temperature ranges like 20°C to 22°C or (20°C - 22°C)

Comment: I would apply the same usage to temperatures as well. The purpose is to be clear to those reading as well as to those hearing what is read out loud.